# Finding joing MGF given conditional distribution?

Tags: probability

> Every day, the 30 employees at an auto plant each have probability
>   0.03 of having one accident and zero probability of having more than one accident. Given there was an accident, the probability of it being
>   major is 0.01. All other accidents are minor. The numbers and
>   severities of employee accidents are mutually independent. Let X and Y
>   represent the numbers of major accidents and minor accidents,
>   respectively, occurring in the plant today. Determine the joint moment
>   generating function $M_{XY}(s,t)$

**Correct answer: $(0.0003e^s + 0.0297e^t + 0.97)^{30}$**

My work: I have that

X = number of minor accidents ~ binom(n=30, p=0.0297) and

Y|X=x ~ binom(n=30-x, p=0.0003)

We want to find joint mgf $M_{XY}(s, t) = E[e^{sX+tY}] = ?$
How do I incorporate the info about conditional distribution in here?

Answer (score 2):

Let $Z$ denote the number of accidents irrepspective of their severities. Then the number of major acc's $X|Z=n\sim Binom(n, 0.01)$, while the number minor acc's $Y| Z=n\sim Binom(n, 0.99)$. Note that $X= \sum_1^{30} X_i$ and $Y= \sum_1^{30}$, where the $(X_i,Y_i)$ pairs are iid with $X_i \sim Ind(0.03\cdot 0.01)$ and $Y\sim Ind(0.03\cdot 0.99)$ and so 
$$ E[e^{sX+tY}] =(E[e^{sX_1+tY_1}])^{30} $$ 
Note that $X_1$ and $Y_1$ are not independent. 
$$E[e^{sX_1+tY_1}] = e^s 0.03\cdot0.01 + e^{t} 0.03\cdot 0.99 + 0.97 $$